# how to count property of an ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, .net, expandoobject

I am trying to count the dynamic properties of an ExpandoObject.

I have tried

```
int count = values.ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, Object>>.Count();
```

but it generates error.

Any help?

UPDATE:

how can i read a property at specific index?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax in the first place. What is the error you are getting? What is the dynamic object instance (`values`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) is wrong. Instead of

```
int count = values.ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, Object>>.Count();
```

use

```
int count = ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, Object>>)values).Count;
```

---

You could also cast your object to [`IDictionary<string, object>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then it becomes shorter:

```
int count = ((IDictionary<string, object>)values).Count
```

---

To read a property at specific index, you can use the [`ElementAt` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb299233%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var valueAt5 = ((IDictionary<string, object>)values).ElementAt(5).Value
```

Comment: Wrong: Count is a member of `IEnumerable<T>`. It should be `Count` "as is" :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer `Count` is a property of `ICollection<T>`. You're talking about `Count` extension method

Comment: @sloth, please do me another favour- how can i read a property at specific index?

Comment: Well, you should post a *new* question about this, but since it's quite easy to do: after casting to `ICollection....` or `IDictionary....`, use the `ElementAt` extension method: `((ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, Object>>)values).ElementAt(1).Value`

Comment: Is it even well-defined which value is the fifth one, given that you can both add and remove values? It is not clearly guaranteed in the spec which order the values will be enumerated in. For example, what order do you expect here: `dynamic values = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject(); values.Hello = 1; values.how = 2; values.are = 3; ((IDictionary<string, object>)values).Remove("how"); values.you = 4; values.how = 5; foreach (var pair in values) { Console.WriteLine(pair); }`. I can reveal that it is different from the order of a non-dynamic `Dictionary<,>` with the samme adds and removes.

Comment: I don't know if it makes sense get a property by an index (you'll have to ask the OP). Nonetheless, the `ExpandoObject` is quite different from a regular `Dictionary<,>`. While the order of items in a  `Dictionary<,>` is non-deterministic due to the hashing of the keys, the keys of a `ExpandoObject` are kept in order (also, removed and later re-added keys are going to be reused). So for your example, I would expect the following order: `Hello:1`, `how:5`, `are:3`, `you:4` since the key `how` was added as second property.

Answer (score 1):

`ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, thus you need to cast it to this interface and you'll be able to access `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Count`.